# Do we really want Jon Skeet facts to be first on Google?

Tags: discussion, google, search, fun

Recently I was searching Google for "Meta Stackoverflow" and what should appear but "Jon Skeet facts" nice and big underneath "Meta Stackoveflow".

[image]

Now that question really is awesome and made me laugh; but do we really want it to appear in Google searches like that?  It might appear to be seriously un-serious for new users and first time visitors for a site like this.

I'm not sure there is anyway to remove it from that exact spot in Google without removing it completely, but I'm kind of wondering if it's good for the site when its the first thing someone will see on searching...

Comment: I'd rather have Jon Skeet, a bit of research and a Chuck Norris reference than anything else... Whilst people need to find Stackoverflow, it's not going to seriously hurt traffic. I'd happily be wronged by SE conducting multivariate testing!

Comment: BTW - when I run the same query, Mr Skeet doesn't even get a sniff!

Comment: Who will google "Meta Stackoverflow" and does not already know about Mr. Skeet?

Comment: Try as I might, I cannot see a problem with this.

Comment: why ? this is meaning less StackOverflow  not Mr. John skeet (btw i am really fan of his knowledge)

Comment: Google Search is customized per visitor, it's not the same for two different people. I've seen it many times by now. It probably identified you visited that link many times before or whatever algorithm Google is using to manipulate the results based on your history, past searches and likely even emails if you have gmail.

Comment: Downvoting as I don't agree with Jon Skeet facts being on Google search results for Meta (but that means I agree with you, again, welcome to the joys of voting on meta) but at the same time, I don't know how much we can influence what Google chooses to show.  But we could *delete* it (which I'm happy to do), because, it doesn't do much to contribute to meta.  Just as it didn't on Stack Overflow (why this was the dumping ground, I don't know).  Jon should host it on his blog (which I'm sure he's open to), or it should be put in his about page.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd  That's interesting because I've tried this on three different browsers and two computers, both logged in and not logged into Google; but I always see Jon Skeet answers... I've only visited that question like 3 times total anyway..

Comment: @Seth are you logged in into gmail in both computers? I really don't know how Google works it magic, but they must store the user stats **somewhere**.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No I wasn't..

Comment: Hmm... so I'm really baffled. Maybe region-related according to IP?

Comment: Wherever you are, Google is watching you!

Answer (score 9):

Well, I get [animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/141525/animuson):

> [image]

As there's no way for SE to completely control what Google displays, removing content that people want to stay, just to keep it out of Google's clutches, seems unnecessary. I assume that animuson would prefer to remain :-).

Also, this is *meta*. If people are searching for Stack Overflow and this comes up I can see your point; meta is... [different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying).

Comment: So have you been stalking Animuson? :P

Comment: I think he's just edited a few to many questions so he's linked everywhere :-).